# chrome extension tabs.onUpdated analog for Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I have some google chrome extension that uses tabs.onUpdated event (I need to be notified when the tab url is changed). Now I want to make the same extension for Firefox. But I cannot find the proper event. Does it exist or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Listening to events on all tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs), and some code samples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners).